# Ionic Socket.io client iOS: Not receiving data via event listener

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, socket.io

I have built an iOS app using the Ionic Framework and Apache Cordova.

It employs the Socket.io client library to open a socket connection to our server and receive updates about user activity.

I create the connection inside an AngularJS service, on the `deviceready` event of the application and attach several listeners which includes `connect`, `disconnect` and `message`.

When running the application for the first time after a fresh install, only the `connect` and `disconnect` events seem to be receiving alerts. However, for some reason if I close the app and start it up again, all three listeners seem to be working fine.

Here is a snippet of my socket instantiation:

```js
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    socket = $window.io.connect(SERVER_URL)
      .on('connect', function() { ... })
      .on('disconnect', function() { ... })
      .on('message', function(data) { ... });
});
```